# Can't filter rows with % mysql using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My idea is to filter rows using % and an IN Variable, I am calling this procedure but it doesn't filter the rows. For example:
if user types 09 the all the rows with the 09... should appear. I have also tried to use concat but also can't filter. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

This is the procedure

```
delimiter //
create procedure p (in cedula1 varchar(10))
begin
    select * from view_pacientes
-- THIS PART IS WRONG BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO CORRECT IT TO WORK PROPERLY.
    where cedula1+"%" like cedula;

end//
```

Comment: This is clearly MySQL so I removed the sql-server tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think this is the syntax you want in MySQL:

```
select *
from view_pacientes
where cedula like concat(cedula1, '%') ;
```

When you are defining a stored procedure in MySQL, I would recommend that you prefix your arguments with something that makes them special.  My preference is `in_` and `out_` for "in" and "out" parameters.